# Plot values for a set of APAC countries in R

Tags: r

I am looking to plot some data for APAC countries for a an upcoming presentation. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lta5Mu1nryQ&list=RDCMUCuWECsa_za4gm7B3TLgeV_A&index=1) however my output is different. Below is some sample data I would like to plot -

```
country_list <- 
    c("Australia", "India", "New Zealand", "Singapore", "Malasia", "China", "Indonesia",
      "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Philipines", "Thailand", "Vietnam", "Korea", "Taiwan", 
      "Cambodia", "Mongolia, Myanmar", "Laos")

values <- 
    c(33260, 24586, 5468, 2698, 2547, 6248, 3654, 6589, 2545, 2548, 835, 536, 565, 665,
      236, 548, 158, 152)

data <- cbind(country_list, values)
```

Then here is how I plot the map -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mapdata)

countries <- 
    map_data("world",
             region = country_list)

data2 <- merge(countries, data, by.x = "region", by.y = "country_list") %>% 
    mutate(values = values %>% as.numeric)

ggplot(data2, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = values))+
    geom_polygon()
```

And here is my output -
[image]

Clearly not fit for a presentation. How can I improve on this map, perhaps add some interactivity to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not reproducible, I can just filter after 0 longitude to show well

```
ggplot(countries %>% filter(long>0), aes(long, lat, group = group))+
geom_polygon()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My apologies, I skipped a line of code after creating the "country_list" and "values". There should be "data <- cbind(country_list, values)"